# Global state resets when navigating links in nextjs app hosted on Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a web app using React, Next14. When I move to a different page, the global state created using createContext is initialized. I had no issues in the local environment, but this problem occurs in the hosting environment (Firebase). What could be the cause of this? Is it because of SSR?